# Why are 'if' and 'else' highlighted with the "Plain Text" colour in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

On my work computer, `if` and `else` are syntax-highlighted with the "Plain Text" colour from preferences, but on my home computer they are highlighted with the "Keywords" colour from preferences. Both are running Xcode 6.3.2 on Yosemite (10.10.3), editing Objective-C (`.m`) files that are correctly recognised as "Objective-C Source" in the Identity and Type inspector. This happens throughout the project - it's not in a compiled-out section of code or anything like that.

Is there any setting or reason why `if` and `else` would not be recognised as keywords in Xcode?

Answer (score -1):

you can change xcode to your own preferences by pressing "command + ," then go to the fonts and colors tab and change it to what ever you want[image]